# Execution time of Queries

Tags: java, mysql

I have some queries which executes in MYsql Yog fast.
But when the same query is called from java class, it takes a long time.
Why is that so?
Can anyone explain me the cause of this?

Here's my query

```
SELECT phymem_util,cpuutil,InBytesPerSec
,uh.time_stamp,hs.totalrsptime 
FROM unix_host_history uh, url_history hs 
WHERE uh.HostID='HS001' AND hs.compID='CP013'
AND SUBSTR(uh.time_Stamp,1,15) = SUBSTR(hs.time_stamp,1,15) 
AND uh.time_stamp BETWEEN '2011-05-27 12:54:10' 
AND '2011-05-27 14:54:10' 
ORDER BY uh.time_stamp
```

Comment: Looks like a java driver problem, but can you be more specific (i.e. post the query and say a word about how you connect to your db)?

Comment: please post updates to your question and not on the answers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Is the query *executing* slow from Java, or is it taking longer because you're unnecessarily retrieving large, unneeded columns of data over a network?

Comment: the query is executing slow in java this is my query                      SELECT phymem_util,cpuutil,InBytesPerSec,uh.time_stamp,hs.totalrsptime FROM unix_host_history uh, url_history hs  
WHERE uh.HostID='HS001' AND hs.compID='CP013'AND SUBSTR(uh.time_Stamp,1,15) = SUBSTR(hs.time_stamp,1,15) 
AND uh.time_stamp BETWEEN '2011-05-27 12:54:10' AND '2011-05-27 14:54:10' ORDER BY uh.time_stamp

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're creating a connection each time? I've slipped up with this before - use a profiler for more info